# SQL Server, checking two columns with cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

**Summary of requirement:**
Whenever a customer enters a new order, the credit card information and uses code are checked in front of old orders. If there is a different client that used the same credit card, the information will be entered into a new table to verify the customer data

**Issue I am facing:**
The problem is that the condition of same customer and same credit doesn't work...

**What I have tried:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_credit_card
ON dbo.orders
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @O_ID VARCHAR (20)
    DECLARE @O_Date Datetime
    DECLARE @O_Made_By VARCHAR (255)
    DECLARE @O_Credit VARCHAR(50)
    BEGIN
        IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','Credit_Card_CURSOR')>=-1
        BEGIN
            DEALLOCATE Credit_Card_CURSOR
        END

        DECLARE Credit_Card_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
            SELECT [order-id], [date], [made-by], [paid-with]
            FROM inserted

        OPEN Credit_Card_CURSOR

        FETCH NEXT FROM Credit_Card_CURSOR INTO @O_ID, @O_Date, @O_Made_By, @O_Credit
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            IF @O_Made_By IN (SELECT o.[Made-by]
                              FROM Orders o
                              WHERE o.[Made-by] = @O_Made_By 
                                AND o.[paid-with] = @O_Credit)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE DBO.orders
                SET [approved] = 'ok'
                WHERE [Made-by] = @O_Made_By
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO DBO.[Security_warrnings]
                VALUES (@O_ID, @O_Credit) 
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM Credit_Card_CURSOR INTO @O_ID, @O_Date, @O_Made_By, @O_Credit
    END

    CLOSE Credit_Card_CURSOR 
END
```

Comment: ok, and your question is?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard, also known as PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) I would recommend researching it.  As a general rule the storage of [credit card numbers isn't recommended](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf).

Comment: A cursor inside a trigger..... the absolute ***best*** way to destroy any performance your system might ever have had .... just ***don't do it!***

Comment: And for the sake of anything even close to sane if you are going to store credit card data is MUST be encrypted. A varchar(50) indicates it is not encrypted (at least not properly). I sure hope I don't buy anything on that system as I like to keep my credit card information to myself.

Comment: For the actual issue at hand you should explain "doesn't work". That is the single most useless phrase heard around SO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cursor .You can use `Inserted` Virtual tables...Modify based on your requirement.Below code inserts data into other table if a customer has already made purchase with Same Credit Card Number...

```
Create trigger dbo.test
on yourtable
after insert 
as
Begin
--check if user has made purchase with same CC number
if exists
(select 1 from 
 from 
Orders   o
join
inserted i
on i.O_Made_By =o.O_Made_By 
and i.creditcardnumber=o.creditcardnumber
)
Begin
--he made 
insert into DBO.[Security_warrnings]
select i.orderid,i.creditcardnumber
from inserted i
join
yoursordertable o
on o.creditcardnumber=i.creditcardnumber

End

End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER order_credit_card
...
BEGIN
    declare @orders_with_warning table ([order-id] int)

    insert into DBO.[Security_warrnings] ([order-id], [paid-with])
        OUTPUT INSERTED.id
        INTO @orders_with_warning([order-id])
    select i.[order-id], i.[paid-with]
    from inserted i
    where exists(select 1 from dbo.Orders o
        where o.[paid-with] = i.[paid-with]
            and o.[Made-by] != i.[Made-by])

    UPDATE o SET
        [approved]= 'ok'
    from DBO.orders o
    inner join inserted i
    on i.[order-id] = o.[order-id]
    where not exists(select 1 from @orders_with_warning ow
        where ow.[order-id] = o.[order-id])
END
```

this try:

```
@O_Made_By in (select  o.[Made-by]
                      from Orders  o
                      where o.[Made-by]=@O_Made_By
```

actually makes no sense. Replace col/var name with number to check the scenario:

```
23 in (select 23 where 23=23)
```